# How to display certain number of random items in android

Tags: android

I am making a simple android app to display random numbers ranging from 1 to 30.
 
The numbers are to be provided in sets depending on the request of user. For example, the user may request to provide 3 or 8 sets of numbers. However, each set must contain only 5 numbers. Nevertheless, I don't know how to get the screen to change to a new line after displaying each set of 5 numbers.

Here is my code so far:

```
draw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view) {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt.getText().toString());
        if (view == draw) {
            String result = "";
            Random num = new Random();
            for (int j=1; j<=inputNum; j++) {
                for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                    int a = 1+num.nextInt(30);
                    displayTxt.setText(result += String.valueOf(a) +"\t" );
                }    
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Can any one help me to change the code so that numbers will be displayed on a new line after each 5 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your if statement for the view is unnecesary because this method is bind to the view.

```
if(view == draw)
```

You could use "\n" instead of "\t" to bring the numbers to the next line. I formatted yout code a little to have it more clear:

```
draw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view) {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt.getText().toString());

        String result = "";
        Random num = new Random();

        for (int j=1; j<=inputNum; j++) {
            for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                int a = 1+num.nextInt(30);
                result += a +"\n";
            }    
        }

        displayText.setText(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer from Doppie. However, your proposed below answer may only display one random number in one line, not a group of 5 numbers in one line as desired.
    draw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view) {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt.getText().toString());

```
    String result = "";
    Random num = new Random();

    for (int j=1; j<=inputNum; j++) {
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            int a = 1+num.nextInt(30);
            result += a +"\n";
        }    
    }

    displayText.setText(result);
}
```

});